# Unable to manipulate the object to a specific format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am trying to manipulate the object into my format of object but it's not working.

I want to convert this array of objects:

```
let details =
[
 { tower_name: 'T1', flats: '["99", "96"]' },
 { tower_name: 'T2', flats: '["98"]' },
 { tower_name: 'T3', flats: '["505"]' }
]
```

And turn it into below format:

```
let towerFlatDetails = 
{
"T1": ["99", "96"],
"T2": ["98"],
"T3": ["505"],
}
```

I tried it this way, but it didn't work:

```
let towerFlatDetails = {}
for (let i in details)
{
    towerFlatDetails.details[i].tower_name = JSON.parse(towerFlatDetails.details[i].flats)
}
```

Comment: I hope you saw may answer, and it makes it clearer what is going on.

Comment: if you want to use for .. in,  your code could also be:  `for (let i in details)
{
    towerFlatDetails[details[i].tower_name] = JSON.parse(details[i].flats)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
let details =
[
 { tower_name: 'T1', flats: '["99", "96"]' },
 { tower_name: 'T2', flats: '["98"]' },
 { tower_name: 'T3', flats: '["505"]' }
];

let result = Object.fromEntries(details.map(({tower_name, flats}) =>
    [tower_name, JSON.parse(flats)]
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Isn't wrapping each mapped answer in an array, then removing the array with Object.fromEntries redundant here?  If you must use functional approaches, wouldn't this make more sense:
`let towerFlatDetails = details.reduce((obj, entry) => (obj[entry.tower_name] = JSON.parse(entry.flats), obj), {})`

Comment: @Frazer, that is a matter of opinion. I'm a fan of `Object.fromEntries`. If one has to repeat this code millions of time, then it might be time to use a basic old-style `for` loop, which will be the most efficient of all options. But in normal use, this is just fine, and in my opinion more readable than `reduce`. But opinions will differ on that.

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: Like I wrote above, that is of course an option. JavaScript offers many alternatives to solve the same problem. I don't think it needs a debate. Anyway, the most costly operation in all this, is not the loop, but `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

towerFlatDetails.details  does not exist, as towerFlatDetails is an empty object, without any properties.  `towerFlatDetails.details[i].tower_name` would need you to have created a details array inside `towerFlatDetails` before it would work.

You need to write:

```js
let details =
[
 { tower_name: 'T1', flats: '["99", "96"]' },
 { tower_name: 'T2', flats: '["98"]' },
 { tower_name: 'T3', flats: '["505"]' }
]

let towerFlatDetails = {}
for (let i of details)
{
  towerFlatDetails[i.tower_name] = JSON.parse(i.flats)
}

console.log(towerFlatDetails);
```

This will use the tower_name as the keys in `towerFlatDetails` and the `flats` as the values.

Also, in your loop, you need to write `of` instead of `in`. `in` uses the index of the entries, `of` uses the values of each entry.

This is the direct translation of the loop you wrote, to working code.